# CheckBox not centered in the TableRow

Tags: android, checkbox, tablelayout, android-tablayout

I'm struggling with aligning checkboxes in a table row in a layout described below.
Where do I go wrong?

You can see in the picture that checkboxes are aligned to the left, and I want them in the center.

I tried all the features in layout-gravity, also tried to put the checkbox inside of another layout, but nothing helped.

[image]

The xml looks like this:

```
<!--  TABLE  -->
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_top_margin"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <!--  HEADER  -->
    <TableRow android:background="@drawable/table_border_header">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border_header"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="HEADER 1"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border_header"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="HEADER 2"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border_header"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="HEADER 3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>

    <!-- SECOND ROW -->
    <TableRow android:background="@drawable/table_border">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="SEED 1"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the problem is that the Checkbox widget uses a regular TextView with the drawableLeft attribute, because it expects text to be shown as well. (This is why you see it centered vertically, but offset slightly to the left.)

You can use a parent layout to achieve this :

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox_star"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

**try this**

```
    <TableRow android:background="@drawable/table_border">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_border"
                android:text="SEED 1"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/table_border"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_border"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet your `0dp` width is setting it to `match_parent`, try `wrap_content`:

```
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Comment: Yes, I know that wrapping around content will work, but then I couldn't distribute columns evenly.